# How to insure well formatted html output from PHP editor

Tags: php, html, markup

I'm have a PHP script that I'm editing in "Text Wrangler" for Mac.

While coding in the IDE, I'm indenting the PHP code so that its more clean and readible.

However, when I check the "view source" of my localhost page on the server, the html output has large amounts of whitespace and is not formatted evenly at all.

Is there anything I can do to get better html output formatting and even indenting?

Comment: When you finish your PHP script, don't close the tag.

Comment: Can you post a snippet or screenshot of your PHP that outputs the HTML so we can see?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to clean up the output of view source? You could take measures to ensure html is indented as expected in source, but it may not be worth the effort for what ultimately doesn't matter.

Comment: Don't do it.  Don't worry about this.  There is no reason to make the output of your HTML look nice.  In fact, there is reason to condense it, removing unnecessary whitespace.  Browsers have nice tools these days for working with the DOM.  You don't need to be viewing the source directly for most debugging.

Comment: What matters more IMO is that the resulting HTML is valid and semantic.  When viewing with your browsers developer tools, as anyone who would want to, would probably do it anyway, it will be viewable in a more orderly/meaningful way.

Comment: For development purposes you could create an output buffer callback implementing http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php

Answer (score 2):

First of all, why do you want to format the output?
Only the browser has to understand it and as we all know, it can even understand the worst HTML tag errors I've ever seen ;)

If you want to debug your webpage, I would recommend you the integrated developer tools in your browser (for example in Google Chrome, press <kbd>F12</kbd>).

But if you really want to indent the output, I would suggest you to use the [ob_*()](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) functions which let you buffer the output so you can pass it to a nice HTML formatter.

Here is a short example using the [Tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) extension:

```
ob_start();

// Now generate and output your HTML using your views, templates or whatever!

$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

// Specify configuration
$config = array(
  'indent'       => true,
  'output-xhtml' => true,
  'wrap'         => 200
);

// Tidy
$tidy = new tidy;
$tidy->parseString($html, $config, 'utf8');
$tidy->cleanRepair();

echo $tidy;
```

You can also use a callback function for [ob_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php):

```
ob_start(function ($html) {
  // Specify configuration
  $config = array(
    'indent'       => true,
    'output-xhtml' => true,
    'wrap'         => 200
  );

  // Tidy
  $tidy = new tidy;
  $tidy->parseString($html, $config, 'utf8');
  $tidy->cleanRepair();

  return str_val($tidy);
});

// Now generate and output your HTML using your views, templates or whatever!

ob_flush();
```

Comment: +1 if you can suggest a decent output buffer function for formatting... although I certainly hope nobody uses it.

Comment: @Brad Just done. You're right, there is **really NO need** for this!

Answer (score 0):

Tab indenting is not ubiquitous for a reason. A tab size can vary depending on the editor you view the output in. It also affects alignment of across multiple lines. Use spaces if you want alignment across multiple lines.

However, I generally don't think one should care about aligning HTML output the user gets, because the user will never look at your HTML or care about it, nor should they have to. All they should see is the parsed result in their browser. This really shouldn't matter to you at all. In fact it's a waste of bandwidth and offers no benefit to the end-user whatsoever.